# in SQS - Does a change in visibility timeout affects In-flight messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a queue with one "heavy" message being sent/receive occasionally.

The configured visibility timeout is currently at the maximum of 12 hours.

However, I identified the message got stuck on the consumer, and I want to return it to the queue for a retry (so it will be consumed again by another consumer).

Does reducing the visibility timeout (temporarily) affect message already in-flight?

Is there any other way to force making the message visible?

Comment: I doubt it. Give it a try and let us know what you find!

Comment: When I changed it didn't change it after the fact, I mean message didn't return immediately. So I think it didn't change on existing message.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `ReceiptHandle` for a message, you can call [`change_message_visibility()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.change_message_visibility).

The Receipt Handle refers to the specific 'fetch' of the message, rather than the message itself. The `ReceiptHandle` value is provided in response to the `ReceiveMessage()` command, so it is only available to the code that actually retrieved the message from the queue.